# using then() in promise

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming

I'm using promise in the block of code below, 2 first then() I dont return any value, so i wonder that is the function in the first then() called before the function in the next then(). Im using typescript in angular 2. Thank you :D

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(()=>{
      this.getListStatus();
    })
    .then(()=>{
      return this._laundryServiceOrderService.findAll(true, offset, this.itemsPerPage, filterQuery)
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.orders = response.data;
      this.totalItems = response.totalItems;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      FlashMessage.setError(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: _"I dont return any value"_ Why do you not return a value? What is purpose of `Promise.resolve()`?

Comment: I think the then() use the response returned from the previous then

Comment: @NhanNguyen: Correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> first then() I dont return any value, so i wonder that is the function in the first then() called before the function in the next then().

Yes, it is. (This can trivially be checked with a debugger.)

It doesn't matter that it doesn't return a value; that's effectively the same as doing `return undefined`. So the next callback in the chain will see `undefined` as the resolution value, but since that next callback doesn't care about the resolution value, that's fine.

Here's a simple example demonstrating it:

```js
Promise.resolve("a")
  .then(result => {
    console.log("First callback got: " + result);  // Gets "a"
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Second callback got: " + result); // Gets undefined
    return "b";
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Third callback got: " + result);  // Gets "b"
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("There's no error above, this won't get triggered.");
  });
```